# Getting multiple rows after using max() and group by

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to assign a segment to an `xml_id` based on the whichever segment the `xml_id` has the most active properties in. I've written a query to this:

I'm creating a table with a select like so:

```
create table schema.table4 as
select
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    xml_id,
    segment as xml_segment,
    max(property_count)
from(
    select
        t1.yyyy_mm_dd,
        t2.xml_id,
        t3.segment,
        count(t1.hotel_id) as property_count
    from(
        select
            yyyy_mm_dd,
            hotel_id
        from
            schema.table1
        where
            is_active = 1
            and yyyy_mm_dd = "2020-10-01"
    ) t1
    left join(
        select
            yyyy_mm_dd,
            hotel_id,
            xml_id
        from
            schema.table2
        where
            yyyy_mm_dd = "2020-10-01"
            and xml_id is not null
    ) t2 on t2.hotel_id = t1.hotel_id and t2.yyyy_mm_dd = t1.yyyy_mm_dd
    inner join
        schema.table3 t3 on t3.hotel_id = t1.hotel_id
    group by
        1,2,3
) x
group by
    1,2,3
```

However, when I query this table I can see multiple segments per `xml_id`. I would have expected only the segment with the `MAX()` property_count would be inserted. How come this isn't the case?

```
select
    xml_id, count(*)
from
    schema.table4
```

Shows multiple rows where the `xml_id` has two and three rows. I need it to be only one row and the segment should be the one with the highest `property_count`.

Some sample output below. `xml_id` inherits the segment in which it has the most properties.

---

t1:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | hotel_id | is_active |
|------------|----------|-----------|
| 2020-10-01 | 1        | 1         |
| 2020-10-01 | 2        | 1         |
| 2020-10-01 | 3        | 1         |
| 2020-10-01 | 4        | 1         |
| 2020-10-01 | 5        | 1         |
| 2020-10-01 | 6        | 1         |
| 2020-10-01 | 7        | 0         |
```

t2:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | hotel_id | xml_id |
|------------|----------|--------|
| 2020-10-01 | 1        | 444    |
| 2020-10-01 | 2        | 444    |
| 2020-10-01 | 3        | 444    |
| 2020-10-01 | 4        | 920    |
| 2020-10-01 | 5        | 920    |
| 2020-10-01 | 6        | 920    |
| 2020-10-01 | 7        | null   |
```

t3:

```
| hotel_id | segment |
|----------|---------|
| 1        | Home    |
| 2        | Core    |
| 3        | Core    |
| 4        | Core    |
| 5        | Home    |
| 6        | Home    |
| 7        | Chain   |
```

Expected output:

```
| yyyy_mm_dd | xml_id | segment |
|------------|--------|---------|
| 2020-10-01 | 444    | Core    |
| 2020-10-01 | 920    | Home    |
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: @GMB sample data and output has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to count the number of actives by date, `xml_id` and `segment`.  This is the basic query for this count:

```
select t2.yyyy_mm_dd, t2.xml_id, t3.segment, count(*) as num_actives
from t2 join
     t1
     on t2.hotel_id = t1.hotel_id and
        t2.yyyy_mm_dd  = t1.yyyy_mm_dd join
     t3
     on t3.hotel_id = t2.hotel_id
where t1.is_active = 1
group by t2.yyyy_mm_dd, t2.xml_id, t3.segment;
```

To get the highest value, you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t2.yyyy_mm_dd, t2.xml_id, t3.segment, count(*) as num_actives,
             row_number() over (partition by t2.yyyy_mm_dd, t2.xml_id order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t2 join
           t1
           on t2.hotel_id = t1.hotel_id and
              t2.yyyy_mm_dd  = t1.yyyy_mm_dd join
           t3
           on t3.hotel_id = t2.hotel_id
      where t1.is_active = 1
      group by t2.yyyy_mm_dd, t2.xml_id, t3.segment
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```